# Programmatically detect if any line in a buffer is wrapping?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an idea for a possibly cool/probably stupid emacs script which would dynamically resize text to fill available space.

One thing I can't seem to figure out is how to query the current buffer to see if any lines are currently being wrapped. How would I do it?

Comment: Have you considered using machine learning?

Comment: @cheez always do, its the hot new thing of the season!:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if any lines are wrapped in the current buffer with function like this:

```
(defun wrapped-lines-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((long-line-regexp 
           (format "^.\\{%d\\}.+$" (window-body-width))))
      (search-forward-regexp long-line-regexp nil t))))
```

As noted in the comments, this doesn't take into account the buffer's font size.  Since buffers can have a mix of different sized fonts,  the window text pixel size needs to be tested.  Try this:

```
(defun wrapped-lines-p ()
  (let ((window-width-pixels (window-body-width nil t)))
    (> (car (window-text-pixel-size nil nil nil (1+ window-width-pixels)))
       window-width-pixels)))
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't take into account when font is increased or decreased? For example I just tried it with ielm targeting a buffer and it gave me the same answer when I ran it normally (no wrapping) and when I did `text-scale-increase` to up the font size until there *was* wrapping.

Comment: Updated the answer to work correctly if the text scale has been adjusted.

Comment: Thanks! will try it out later

Answer (score 1):

Note that "any lines are currently being wrapped" is a property of the *window*, not the *buffer*.

Given a `window`, you can scan it from top visible line to bottom and compare line length to `window-width`:

```
(defun window-long-lines-p ()
  "Return t is any visible line in the current window is longer than window width."
  (save-excursion
    (move-to-window-line -1)
    (let ((end (point)) here
          found-long-line)
      (move-to-window-line 0)
      (while (and (not found-long-line)
                  (< (setq here (point)) end))
        (when (< (window-width)
                 (- (progn (forward-line 1)
                           (point))
                    here))
          (setq found-long-line t)
          (message "long line: %d" (1- (line-number-at-pos)))))
      found-long-line)))
```

Comment: This will break down miserably if you use proportional fonts or if your chars don't all have the same width.  Even just a TAB character will lead to errors.